# using scalajs and d3 to create a histogram

Tags: javascript, scala, d3.js, scala.js

I'm trying to use the scala-js facade over d3 to create a histogram for roughly 1000 integers I have. I've used one of the examples to create a kinda working model, but there are some style aspects I can't really work out. [image]

Ideally I'd like to justify the entire histogram to the left against the y-axis or at the very least center the entire thing and move the y-axis over so it's close. I'd also like to have this histogram be more of a density plot with the percentages on the y-axis, but I haven't really found anyway to do that just yet.

```
val margin = js.Dictionary("top" -> 30, "right" -> 30, "bottom" -> 30, "left" -> 30)
val width = 2500 - margin("left") - margin("right")
val height = 500 - margin("top") - margin("bottom")

val x = d3.scale.identity().range(js.Array(values.min, values.max))

val data = d3.layout.histogram().bins(x.ticks(100))(values)

val mm: js.Function2[Bin[Double], Double, Double] = { (x: Bin[Double], y: Double) => x.y }

val m = d3.max(data, mm)

val y = d3.scale.linear().domain(js.Array(0, m)).range(js.Array(height, 0))

val xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom")
val yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickValues(js.Array(20, 40, 60, 80)).orient("right")

dom.document.getElementById("scalajsShoutOut").textContent = data.join(", ")

val svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin("left") + margin("right"))
  .attr("height", height + margin("top") + margin("bottom"))
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin("left") + "," + margin("top") + ")")

val ff = (d: Bin[Double]) => "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"

val bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", ff)

val rect = (d: Bin[Double]) => height - y(d.y)

bar.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 1)
  .attr("width", x(data(0).dx) - 1)
  .attr("height", rect)

bar.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".75em")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("x", x(data(0).dx) / 2)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text((d: Bin[Double]) => formatPercent(d.y))

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + ", 0)")
  .call(yAxis)
```

Does anyone have any insight about how I can achieve this effect? Thanks for any help, sorry my code is so hacky right now.